# What can I do to handle different requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

### Preface

I have created an ASP.NET Code Web API using Visual Studio 2022 to familiarise myself with the topic of "Web APIs".

[image: Template]

I have converted the project to `.NET 5`.

In the `MyControllers.cs` I have so far code for a `Get` and for a `Post` request.

I have removed the `WeatherForecast.cs` created by Visual Studio. I have also set in the `launchSettings.json` that the browser jumps to `MyController` from the beginning.

To practice **Dependency Injection**, I added another project called `TextRepository` (a class library) to the assembly. I had written a text file with another Visual Studio project that contains the numbers from 0–99. This text file is read in and returned in the `Get method` of `MyController.cs`. Now the numbers are displayed in the browser when called. I had also included the interface `INumberRepository`.

[image: text file]

To practise the whole thing *again*, I created another repository: `ImageRepository`. The aim is to find all pictures in the folder *Pictures* and store them in a List. To do this, I downloaded *System.Drawing.Common* from the NuGet package manager.

[image: Solution Explorer]

### Question for you:

I am still struggling a bit to request the API in the browser for different purposes. I still want to use the call https://localhost:44355/api/My for displaying the numbers in the browser, i.e., the Get method. How can I make it so that I use a different link to transfer the image data? I am concerned with the call to the API – do I have to write a second Get function? – And about transferring the bytes of the images.

If anyone wonders what the images are: I have created 2 test images for this purpose (1920 pixels ×1080 pixels).

[image: blue and black images]

#### WebApplication2

**in Startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped<TextRepository.INumberRepository, TextRepository.NumberTextFileRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ImageRepository.IImageTransferRepository, ImageRepository.ImageTransferRepository>();
```

**MyController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TextRepository;
using ImageRepository;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly INumberRepository numberRepository;
        private readonly IImageTransferRepository imageRepository;
        public MyController(INumberRepository numberRepository, IImageTransferRepository imageTransferRepository)
        {
            this.numberRepository = numberRepository;
            this.imageRepository = imageTransferRepository;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<int>> Get()
        {
            List<int> numbers = this.numberRepository.GetNumbers();
            List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> foundImages = this.imageRepository.GetImages();
            return Ok(numbers);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] DataTransferObject transferObject)
        {
            return Ok(transferObject.PassedString + $" {transferObject.Zahl}");
        }
    }
}
```

#### TextRepository

**TextFileParser.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace TextRepository
{
    public class TextFileParser
    {
        public static List<int> ReadAllData(string path)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
            }
            string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
            if (allLines == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("War null");
            }
            if (allLines.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Die Datei enthält 0 Zeilen.");
            }
            if (allLines.Length == 1)
            {
                return new List<int>();
            }
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i < allLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(allLines[i], out int result))
                {
                    numbers.Add(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"In der Textdatei, in Zeile {i + 1}, ist eine inkorrekte Zahl aufgetreten.");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

**NumberTextFileRepository**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TextRepository
{
    public class NumberTextFileRepository : INumberRepository
    {
        public List<int> GetNumbers()
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo Root = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            return TextFileParser.ReadAllData(Root.Parent.FullName + "\\Textdatei.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

**INumberRepository.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TextRepository
{
    public interface INumberRepository
    {
        List<int> GetNumbers();
    }
}
```

#### ImageTransferRepository

**ImageTransferRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ImageRepository
{
    public class ImageTransferRepository : IImageTransferRepository
    {
        public List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> GetImages()
        {
            return ImageTransfer.GetImagesFromFolder(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageTransfer.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ImageRepository
{
    public class ImageTransfer
    {
        public static List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> GetImagesFromFolder(string path)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
            }

            List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();
            fileInfos.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles().Where(f => IsValidFile(f)));
            fileInfos = fileInfos.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList(); // The newest image should be at the top of the list.

            return (from FileInfo file in fileInfos select new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.FullName)).ToList();
        }
        private static bool IsValidFile(FileInfo File)
        {
            return File.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".bmp") ^ File.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpeg") ^ File.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") ^ File.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".png");
        }
    }
}
```

**IImageTransferRepository.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ImageRepository
{
    public interface IImageTransferRepository
    {
        List<Bitmap> GetImages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still want to use the call https://localhost:44355/api/My for displaying the numbers in the browser, i.e., the Get method. How can I make it so that I use a different link to transfer the image data? I am concerned with the call to the API – do I have to write a second Get function? – And about transferring the bytes of the images.

If you want to return `List<int> numbers` and `List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> foundImages` together,you can try to create a class which contains the two lists.Or you need to write a second Get function.

```
public class TestModel {
        public List<int> numbers { get; set; }
        public List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> foundImages { get; set; }

    }
```

Get function:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<TestModel > Get()
        {   
            TestModel t=new TestModel();
            t.numbers = this.numberRepository.GetNumbers();
            t.foundImages = this.imageRepository.GetImages();
            return Ok(t);
        }
```

If you want to create a second Get function,here is the demo:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<int>> Get()
        {
            List<int> numbers = this.numberRepository.GetNumbers();
            return Ok(numbers);
        }
[HttpGet("foundImages")]//route will be https://localhost:44355/api/My/foundImages 
        public ActionResult<List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>> Get()
        {
            List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> foundImages = this.imageRepository.GetImages();
            return Ok(foundImages);
        }
```